Coordinate-free determinant
The defintion of the determinant of an endomorphism T on V (n-dimensional) via the exterior power $\Lambda^n V$ and its basis $v_1\wedge ... \wedge v_n $ of a vector space is given (wikipedia)

$T(v_1\wedge ... \wedge v_n)$ = $det(T)* v_1\wedge ... \wedge v_n$

in my lecture it was defined that

For $w \in (\Lambda^n V)^*, T^*(w) = det(T)*w $, where $T^*(w) = w(T(v_1)\wedge ... \wedge T(v_n)) $

it seems to me that the second defintion uses the isomorphism between $\Lambda^n V$  and alternating multilinear forms. Could someone provide more information on the equality of the two definitons ?

There is a typo here. Double-check your “where $T^*(w)=$ … “

For $T:V\to V$, the induced map $T:\Lambda^n V\to\Lambda^n V$ satisfies $T(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)=T(v_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge T(v_n)$. If $w\in(\Lambda^n V)^$, then $w:\Lambda^n V\to\mathbb{F}$ and $T^(w)=w\circ T$. Do you see the connection now?

The vector space $\wedge ^n V$ is one dimensional, and its dual is the one dimensional vector space of alternate $n$-forms. The determinant can be viewed as a linear map from $\wedge ^n V$ to itself and is a scalar and is equal to its transposed map.

It seems that you didn't address the OP's question.

Would you prefer $(\wedge ^n V)^=\wedge ^n V^$
